# None of the fields in the record map to the columns apache-nifi

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, apache-nifi

I am trying to insert records from `Oracle` to `Postgresql`. To do it, I use 
`QueryDatabaseTableRecord` -> `PutDatabaseRecord`

**QueryDatabaseTableRecord** -> Fetch from Oracle
`Writer -> CSV`

**PutDatabaseRecord** -> to insert record to Postgresql.

`Reader -> CSV`

A few weeks ago, I faced with the same issue with `Postgresql`. [cloudera question](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/none-of-the-fields-in-the-records-map-to-the-columns-CSV-to/td-p/280308).

This time I made `schema` to public and `Translate field name : false`

I have changed `postgresql` table columns into block letters as I have used in oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for this. Its not directly related `Apache-NiFi`, kind of `Postgresql` related thing.

Data taken from `Oracle` comes with Upper-case headers. Headers **MUST** be converted to Lower-case. Creating `postgresql` columns with Upper-case wont solve this issue.

To do this, I have used `Replace Text` processor.

```
Search Value : MY_COLUMN1,MY_COLUMN2
Replacement Value : my_column1,my_column2
```

I hope this will help someone who is trying to get data from `Oracle` and put them back into `Postgresql`.